# Access API JSON data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, geolocation

I'm Trying to build a weather app by using the ip-api to get users current latitude and longitude and pass that into the darksky api URL to get the weather JSON data. I get the lat and lon logging fine, but I get the following errors for the Darksky call. Am I doing something wrong by trying to pull the data from one API and use it another? Or is it just in the way I'm trying to do it?

***-GET 'dark sky api url' 401***

***-Access to fetch at 'https://api.darksky....' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy***

```
getLocation = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const api_call = await fetch("http://ip-api.com/json");
  const data = await api_call.json();
  console.log(data.lat, data.lon);
  let lattitude = data.lat;
  let longitude = data.lon;

  const weather_call = await fetch(`https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${API_KEY}/${lattitude},${longitude}`);
  const weather_data = await weather_call.json();
  console.log(weather_data);
}

  render() {
    const {to, getLocation, ...rest} = this.props;
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Landing getLocation={this.getLocation}/>
        </div>
      );

  }
```

Comment: Do you still get the error if you change to `fetch('https://api.darksky...', { mode: 'no-cors' }) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do I get the error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource when I try to call the API?
We take security very seriously at Dark Sky. As a security precaution we have disabled cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) on our servers.

Your API call includes your secret API key as part of the request. If you were to make API calls from client-facing code, anyone could extract and use your API key, which would result in a bill that you'd have to pay. We disable CORS to help keep your API secret key a secret.

To prevent API key abuse, you should set up a proxy server to make calls to our API behind the scenes. Then you can provide forecasts to your clients without exposing your API key.

you can search here https://darksky.net/dev/docs/faq

Comment: I think you should clarify in your answer that the security risk has nothing to do with CORS... only that you're trying to discourage developers from embedding their API keys where they are exposed.  Having CORS enabled is quite secure when used correctly.  In fact, there are use cases where accessing your API with CORS requests would be desirable.  Suppose I wanted to make a client for your service where users entered their own API key.  By disabling CORS, the data must be proxied, exposing their key to my servers.  Maybe this isn't a use case you're concerned with, but it is a valid one.

Comment: i agree, but in this case, darksky make that rule. I only copy the information for faq.

Comment: Update your answer then, rather than copying/pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're exposing the API key on your frontend. You have to make the call from your backend.